# Extent Report in Jenkins is displaying blank icon for attached screenshots

Tags: selenium, jenkins, extentreports

I have generated a runnable jar of my project, and running it on other machine through jenkins.
Jar file executing successfully and generating extent report also,
but there is a blank icon on the place of screenshots.

I have searched on google but did not find any relevant solution to solve my problem.

[image: First failure case screenshot attached with the Extent Report]

[image: Second failure case screenshot attached with the Extent Report]

- I am using Intellij IDE and opening the extent report by using the option of "Open in Browser".
  When there are more than two screenshots attached(like in above case) with the extent report, it is showing blank icon and showing error when opening the image in new tab.
  (When opening the extent report by going into the folder where it is actually saved in the system, it is working as expected).

[image: Error when opening the screenshot in the new tab of browser]

My code:

```
       @BeforeTest
            public void setExtent() {
                extent = new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/test-output/Login.html", true);
                System.out.println("KKKKKKK");
                extentTest = extent.startTest("Start the Execution");
                extent.addSystemInfo("Host Name", "Live Contract");
                extent.addSystemInfo("User Name", "Shivam Goyal");
                extent.addSystemInfo("Environment", "Develop");
                extentTest.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Test Execution started");
        
            } 
    
       
    
    public static String getScreenshot(WebDriver driver, String screenshotName) {
                String dateName = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss").format(new Date());
                TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
                File src = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/test-output/"+ screenshotName + dateName + ".png";
                File destination = new File(path);
        
                try {
                    FileUtils.copyFile(src, destination);
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("Capture Failed" +e.getMessage());
                }
                return path;
            }
    
    @Test
        public void openURL() throws IOException, InterruptedException, HeadlessException, UnsupportedFlavorException {
            System.out.println("test openWeb");
    
            extentTest = extent.startTest("LC1_1.1 - Verify the Login Panel of \"Berater\".");
    
            try {
                //Accept All cookies
                driver.findElement(By.className(property.getProperty("LiveContractCookies"))).click();
    
    
                //Test case LC1_1.1 Open the given URL in Browser (Aufruf der entsprechenden URL im Browser)
    
                boolean Homescreen = driver.findElement(By.name(property.getProperty("BeraterLoginPanelName1"))).isDisplayed();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
    
                Assert.assertTrue(Homescreen);
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
        @Test
        public void checkEntryFields() throws InterruptedException {
            extentTest = extent.startTest("LC1_1.2 - Verify the Entry fields on Berater's login panel");
            try {
                driver.findElement(By.className(property.getProperty("LiveContractCookies"))).click();
    
                WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name(property.getProperty("username_fieldName")));
                WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name(property.getProperty("password_fieldName")));
    
    
                username.click();
                username.sendKeys("Test123");
                password.click();
                password.sendKeys("9876554");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(username.getText());
    
                String usnm = username.getAttribute("value");
                String pass = password.getAttribute("value");
    
                System.out.println("Something happening");
    
                Assert.assertEquals("Test123", usnm);
                Assert.assertEquals("98765", pass);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
        }
    
    
        @AfterMethod
        public void tearDown(ITestResult result) {
            if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE){
                extentTest.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is" +result.getName());
                extentTest.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is" +result.getThrowable());
    
                String screenshotPath = Login.getScreenshot(driver, result.getName());
                extentTest.log(LogStatus.FAIL, extentTest.addScreenCapture(screenshotPath));
            }
            else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP){
                extentTest.log(LogStatus.SKIP, "Test Case Skipped is "+result.getName());
            }
            else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS){
                extentTest.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test Case Passed is "+result.getName());
            }
    
                extent.endTest(extentTest);
                //extent.flush();
                driver.quit();
                //tempDriver.quit();
                //tempDriver.quit();
    
    
        }
    
        @AfterTest
        public void endReport() {
            try{
                extent.flush();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.getMessage();
            }
    
            //extent.close();
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like the paths aren't reachable from the report.  Haev you chaed the file system to make sure the images are where you expect and are permissioned correctly?

Comment: Yes, i think, i tried to save my extent report and screenshots in the same folder, but that was not enough. Do i need to add any folder or some other setting in the Jenkins or is it an error in my class?